# How to add the ID to URL when click tab

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to add the current id of  tag to the end of current URL in WordPress, how to to this ?!

My html css code is:

```
<ul class="pc ">
    <li id="tab1" class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li id="tab2"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li id="tab3"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li id="tab4" class="cl_pr_tab"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I tried using jquery for the test but not work

```
$("ul.pc > li").tabs({ 
   select: function(event, ui) { 
      window.location = "#" + ui.tab;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use pushState for your case

```js
window.history.pushState({ path: window.location.href+'#123' }, '', window.location.href+'#123');
```

Like this:

```
let location = window.location.href;
$("ul.pc > li").tabs({ 
   select: function(event, ui) { 
      window.history.pushState({ path: `${location}#${ui.tab}` }, '', `${location}#${ui.tab}`);
   }
});
```